# How to override configLocation of a Maven Checkstyle Plugin

Tags: java, maven, configuration

I want to override a `configLocation` that is originally declared in a configuration of a `maven-checkstyle-plugin` in the parent pom.xml.

But when I'm executing `mvn clean package` in the child project it's ignoring `<configLocation>child-stylecheck.xml</configLocation>` and uses `parent-stylecheck.xml` instead. The `child-stylecheck.xml` is located in the root of the project next to the `pom.xml`.

What could be wrong in my configurations?

Plugin configuration in the **parent** `pom.xml`

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-checkstyle-version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>parent-stylecheck.xml</configLocation>
          <outputFileFormat>xml</outputFileFormat>
          <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
```

Plugin configuration in the **child** `pom.xml`

```
     <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${checkstyle-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <configLocation>child-stylecheck.xml</configLocation>
                        <suppressionsFile>parent-stylecheck.xml</suppressionsFile>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the child configure the plugin (not define it within pluginManagement)?

Comment: @JanvandenBerg actually the `child` pom is the root pom of the project. And the `parent` is a library with global configurations It is defined in the child's pom in a <parent> tag.